# How to share score on facebook wall through Facebook Connect?

Tags: facebook

I have a game on my website and I want to share the score on wall facebook account wall. I have searched and found that it can be done with facebook connect, but through facebook connect I am able to share only URL of any page. So can anyone kindly help me and tell how share score and my custom message through facebook connect. Thanks

Comment: do you find solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a custon message, you would need a Dialog. You can see about them in here:

[Link 1](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs)
and 
[Link 2](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed)

The second link is an extension for what you want. Just fill the data you want/need about your highscore, and it will be ready to display!

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use a dialog. You can make a direct request to the facebook url using the open graph API.

[Take a look](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#publishing)